# Golang многопоточность и конвейер

Tags: многопоточность, golang

При запуске анонимной функции в го рутине, она отрабатывает не корректно. (открывает и парсит не все файлы), хотя если не запускать ее в отдельном потоке, то все отрабатывает нормально.
Помогите разобраться, что я делаю не так.

```
names := make(map[string]bool)
var mutex = &sync.Mutex{}
for _, file := range f {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
            if file.Name[:2] == "HM"{
                names[file.Name] = true
                mutex.Lock()
                xmlFile, err := os.Open(filepath.Join(file.PathUnzipFile))
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("[ERROR] невозможно открыть файл %e \n", err)
                }

                mutex.Unlock()
                defer xmlFile.Close()

                    var hFile ZL_LIST
                    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
                    decoder.CharsetReader = func(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
                        switch charset {
                        case "windows-1251":
                            return charmap.Windows1251.NewDecoder().Reader(input), nil
                        default:
                            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown charset: %s", charset)
                        }
                    }

                    err1 := decoder.Decode(&hFile)
                    if err1 != nil {
                        fmt.Errorf("[ERROR] невозможно декодировать файл %e", err)
                    }
            }

        close(out)
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было воспользоваться группой ожидания действий WaitGroup и передавать в анонимную функцию непосредственно сам экземпляр file
Не сочтите за рекламу, но решение нашел в книге "Go на практике" на странице 97.

```
func (ZL_LIST) Parse(FilesName []*Files) {

    unzipPath, err := filepath.Abs("tmp")

    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(unzipPath)

    f := make([]*Files, 0)
    for _, file := range files {
        fileZip := new(Files)
        if !file.IsDir() && file.Name()[:1] != "." {
            fileZip.Name = file.Name()
            fileZip.PathUnzipFile = filepath.Join(unzipPath, file.Name())
            f = append(f, fileZip)
        }
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("[ERROR] ошибка при получении файлов %v", err)
    }

    names := make(nameMap, 1)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var countHmLmFiles int = -1
    var countHmFiles int = 0
    var countLmFiles int = 0
    var file *Files
    var l sync.Mutex
    for countHmLmFiles, file = range f {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(filename *Files) {
            parseHmLm(filename, &countHmFiles, &countLmFiles, &names, &l)
            //parseHmLm(filename)
            wg.Done()
        }(file)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("[INFO] Прочитано %d файловб из них HM файлов %d и LM файлов %d ", countHmLmFiles+1, countHmFiles, countLmFiles)
}

func parseHmLm(filename *Files, countHmFiles *int, countLmFiles *int, names *nameMap, l *sync.Mutex) {
    fmt.Println("[INFO] считывается файл ", filename.Name, " с заголовком ", filename.Name[:2])

    xmlFile, err := os.Open(filepath.Join(filename.PathUnzipFile))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("[ERROR] невозможно открыть файл %e \n", err)
    }

    defer xmlFile.Close()

    switch filename.Name[:2] {
    case "HM":
        l.Lock()
        (*names)[filename.Name] = true
        (*countHmFiles) += 1
        l.Unlock()
        var hFile ZL_LIST
        decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
        decoder.CharsetReader =  charset
        err := decoder.Decode(&hFile)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("[ERROR] невозможно декодировать файл %e", err)
        }
    case "LM":
        l.Lock()
        (*countLmFiles) += 1
        l.Unlock()
        var lFile PERS_LIST
        decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
        decoder.CharsetReader = charset
        err := decoder.Decode(&lFile)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("[ERROR] невозможно декодировать файл %e", err)
        }
    }

}

func charset(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    switch charset {
    case "windows-1251":
        return charmap.Windows1251.NewDecoder().Reader(input), nil
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown charset: %s", charset)
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас там полно гонок. Попробуйте запустить с `-race` при `GORACE="halt_on_error=1"`.

Comment: да, я уже понял это... сейчас работаю над этим

Comment: устранил пролблему с гонками